# Item-Level Permissions in SharePoint List based on Column Value

Tags: sharepoint-online, permissions, lookup-column, power-automate, item-level-permissions

We have a SharePoint site that will be used to handle claims and enquiries. We have three tiers of User with different permissions. All users must be logged-in to access the site:

- Admin
- Internal User ("Approver")
- Guest User (“Client”)

**SharePoint List & Issue**

A SharePoint list is (“Trade List”). The SharePoint List is populated automatically by an integration with a data warehousing system. All Client data arrives in the SharePoint List, there are up to 30+ clients and 5,000 lines of data at any moment. The data is provided in this format to SharePoint List “Trade List”:

| Tax Reg No. | CompanyName | ETD | Cstm No | Entry Date |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 988313294002 | ACME Inc. | 760 | 026751H | 01/04/2021 |

In Column A of ”Trade List” there is a unique tax identifier of the Client.

We wish for each item/row in SharePoint List “Trade List” to only be visible to the logged-in user with the tax identifier in Column A. This is effectively Row-Level Security (“RLS”) for the “Trade List”.

I am comfortable with Power Automate and removing permissions/awarding permissions when an item is created. I *would need help specifically with the next step*.

**Identity Table (“ID Table”)**

Through a separate system, we already manage an ID table in this following format:

| fname | lname | CompanyName | Email | Tax Reg No. |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| John | Smith | Acme Inc. | jsmith@... | 988313294002 |
| Joe | Bloggs | NewCo | joe.bloggs@... | 787545492000 |

Implementing item-level permissions on each item in the “Trade List” using a Power Automate flow, based on the column value 'Tax Reg No.' and a lookup for the associated User and email address.

Is anybody able to best advise on how to advise on the Implementation of Row-Level Security (RLS), so that a Client can only see SharePoint List items associated with their unique Tax Reg No. when logged-in?

Answer (score 1):

You could first break the inheriting permissions of the list and delete all the users in it.

Then you could use the power automate like this:
[image]

[image]

The function of 'body' in the screenshot is: body('Send_an_HTTP_request_to_SharePoint_3')['d']['id']

You could change the roledefid according to your need (I use the id for Read permission in my test):

[image]

As a result, when I create a new item, person in the 'person' column will be granted 'Read' permission(In my test, Wendy Li is the site owner, so this account itself has full control).

[image]

You could also read this article for more information:
https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/53927.sharepoint-online-break-inheritance-and-set-list-item-level-permissions-with-power-automate-part-1.aspx

Comment: This is great and really helpful walkthrough. 

I have established this Flow as a 'when item modified' trigger, and I am manually modifying the column of 'Owned By' user, to establish the User who has permission to edit the item.

 If I am looking at a full automation, how would I use Power Automate to 'lookup' the Tax ID in Table 1, and associate this with a User Email/User ID?